# Inserting blocks into custom places

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

In Magento 1

I can edit `local.xml` like so:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="above_main" template="page/html/banner.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

I can edit a template file like so:

```
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

        <?php // MY EDIT: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('above_main');

        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

<!-- rest of page... -->
```

This will end up with the file at `page/html/banner.phtml` being inserted into the template at my own custom position, `above_main`.

OK, so my question is:

How do I do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score -1):

There are few methods for achieving this.
Simple one is as below.

Create file with name

```
> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_<module youwantto
> override>/templates/<your phtml file path>
```

Do your customization there

Same way
Create xml file with same name as base module file in

```
app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_<module youwantto override>/
layout/<your modulefilexml eg. catalog_product_view.xml>
```

and add your changes there.

let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Further help please! What layout code do I use in the XML file? In the phtml file do I still use `$this->getChildHtml()` - I understand the file structure in Magento 2, what I need information on is the code (mostly the XML) that I need to put into those files

Comment: You can check core phtml files if this is supported or not For eg. to display filter state, it is done like this " echo $block->getChildHtml('state')"
Layout is bit different but mostly its same. Check dev doc for more information on theme part. 
mark my answer accepted if it helped.

Comment: sorry Pallavi, I was asking how to insert a block into a custom place, and all your answer contains is where to create some files and a comment saying "check dev doc".  Until you can answer my original question with something less vague I cannot mark you as correct.